# What exactly is dot dot (..)? Why is its behavior different with symlinks?

Tags: filesystems, directory, symlink, filenames, cd-command

I am trying to understand the nature of `..` (double dot). It seems to point to different targets depending on how you access it.

Example:-

```
    /outer/
        middle/
            inner/
        inner --> ./middle/inner/
```

Now, `/outer/middle/inner/..` leads to `/outer/middle/`, but if I access it through the symbolic link, `/outer/inner/..` leads to `/outer/`. It seems that there are two different `..` here.

What is `..` exactly? symbolic link? hard link? Or is it dynamically generated depending on the path when the directory is accessed? Or perhaps my understanding of symbolic links is wrong.

**Edit:**

Other related observation

```
    /outer/
        middle/
            file
            inner/
               f --> ./../file
        inner --> ./middle/inner/
```

Now if I try to access file through `/outer/inner/f` it works. But it shouldn't since `/outer/inner/../file` does not point to a file. the file is in `/outer/middle/inner/..`. This seem to contradict the behavior in above!?

Comment: Note that symbolic links aren't shortcuts; they're more like pointers.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`..` is a *hard link* to the parent directory which is created as part of the directory entry.

If you issue `ls -ail` in each of these directories, you should see that the following entries all have the same `inode` (first field) and hard link count (third field):

- `..` when executing `ls -ail` in `inner`
- `.` when executing `ls -ail` in `middle`
- `middle` when executing `ls -ail` in `outer`

> Now, /outer/middle/inner/.. leads to /outer/middle/, but if I access it through the symbolic link, /outer/inner/.. leads to /outer/. It seems that there are two different .. here.

There is one `..` entry in `inner`.  If your current working directory is `outer`, you should see the same results (a directory listing of `middle`) from

- `ls -al inner/..`
- `ls -al middle/inner/..`

The only situation in which "accessing" `..` through the symbolic link should provide different behavior is if you `cd` into `inner` using the symbolic link, so that your *logical* working directory (`pwd -L`) differs from your *physical* working directory (`pwd -P`).  In this case, `cd ..` will take you back to `outer` *not* because there is a different `..` entry, but because your shell is keeping track of your *logical* working directory and popping you out one level, rather than referencing the actual `..` entry in `inner`.

This is a convenience provided by, for example `bash` as part of the built-in `cd` command.  You can override this by asking it to change to the actual `..` entry with

```
cd -P ..
```

where `-P` instructs `cd` (as with `pwd` above) to use the physical path.

Comment: Aha, the confusion comes from using `cd` to check. So, correct me if I am wrong, `..` always points to the physical parent, If a symlink uses `..` it will be directed to the actual (physical) parent. The confusion happends only with `cd`ing into directories.

Comment: This is also explains the seconds behaviour. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Theophrastus, `ls -lai` shows you that `/..` is the root directory itself, again (a.k.a. `/.`  or `/`). Unless the file system is broken, there should be no other case where `. == ..`; even when a fs is mounted somewhere it gets the correct `..` of the (temporary) parent (so there is some magic going on there, `..` is not just a simple, static entry in the file system table).