# Why does Linux based OS creates . file same directory and .. file in it's sub-directory? How does it work?

Tags: linux, filesystems

Hello there!

Currently, I am studying shell programming and there i just learned symbolic link , hard link, files , directories- related topics. I am trying to understand-

1. why a directory has two links and when a directory is created - why there are **.** and **..** files in the directory? and how they work?
2. why **.** file in a directory is necessary?

Good explanations will be helpful for me.

Thanks  in advance.

Best regards-
Nazmul

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/22664/117549 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/21847/117549 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/332681/117549

Comment: `.` is useful because it provides a guaranteed name for the current directory; for example, when you type a command, the shell normally looks it up in the directories listed in `$PATH`, but if you say `./`command then the name clearly refers to a file in the current working directory. `..` is not only useful, its essential, because it provides a name for parent directory. They work as you expect -- they behave as if they were hard links to the respective directories; whether they actually exist on disk depends on the specific filesystem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `.` and `..` entries always exist in directories.

<sup>They are not specific to [Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux); all [Unixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix) have them, and [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) is [nearly](https://askubuntu.com/a/636001/64680) requiring them. [GNU Hurd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Hurd) and VSTa have them too. Perhaps [Multics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multics) invented them. [MS-DOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS-DOS) 3 copied them from Unix, so [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows) has them also. IIRC [VMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenVMS) had something similar.</sup>

As soon as some program (your shell, the `/bin/ls` program, your or some other program using [nftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html), etc, etc....) uses [opendir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html), then some [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) will give `.` and (another call to `readdir` will return) `..` (actually it is the underlying [getdents(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getdents.2.html)).

I don't know if they -the `.` and `..` entries- are provided in every [file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) or by some common [VFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_file_system) layer in the kernel (and we should not care). Consider that a successful [mkdir(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mkdir.2.html) creates both `.` and `..` entries (it is at least the illusion provided by the [Linux kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel)).

The kernel path resolution layer handles `.` and `..` (and `/`) appropriately. Read [path_resolution(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html). The file path is used to reference a file (which actually is some [inode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode)), and the same file can have several paths (and sometimes none).

Any system call (listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)) dealing with file [paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)) (such as [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html), [unlink(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unlink.2.html), [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) and many others...) goes thru that path resolution layer in the kernel.

> why `.` file in a directory is necessary?

It is very useful in some cases. For example you could (by some program or some weird command) create a file named `-r` (this is very bad taste). You would use `rm ./-r` to remove it (because `rm -r` has some very different meaning). And your shell uses the [`$PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) variable to find executables. If you have some `ls` executable in the current directory (this is also very bad taste) you need to type `./ls` to get it running (otherwise `/bin/ls` is likely to be found in your `$PATH` by [execvp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execvp.3.html) or equivalent).

<sup>You could even -in principle- have a directory entry for a file named with a single return or tab character, but that is disgusting. How to remove it is left as an exercise to the reader (but it is possible with `rm`).</sup>

Some functions (such as [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html)) are working differently with a file path containing or not a `/`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17716576/841108).

And `..` is useful in [relative file paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Absolute_and_relative_paths). See also [realpath(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realpath.3.html).

A related question is why do processes have a [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) (and each process has its own one, that is why `cd` [needs to be a shell builtin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21580827/841108)). This is at least for convenience (and [historical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Unix) reasons, e.g. legacy), and also for efficiency. On some systems (think of supercomputers with petabytes of disk) a complete file path could be very long (e.g. have several hundreds of characters) and you don't want to type long file paths, or have all programs dealing with them. See also [chdir(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chjdir.2.html), [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html), [chroot(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chroot.2.html).

<sup>On other OSes - notably MS-DOS -, working directories are -slightly- different.</sup>

BTW, files are not a must (and they are conventions and abstractions provided by the [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) kernel). Some experimental academic operating systems don't have files because they are implementing some other [persistence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_(computer_science)) layer. In the 1960s operating systems provided very different files (than what POSIX is requiring today).

<sup>(when you think about them, files are not necessarily the best way to organize information on current computers. Think how difficult it is for you to find a photo amongst many thousands of them, or a letter you wrote many years ago, on your laptop. Let's hope that future OSes will have something better)</sup>

Read [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) (freely downloadable). Implement -as an exercise- your own [unix shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) (or study the source code of existing ones, since they are [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software)). See also [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/398464/50557).

Comment: Actually, working directories are _the same_ in Win32.

Comment: Not only do you not want to *type* a long argument (file path or other), but arguments take up space in the shared buffer for arguments-plus-environment. Better to save a long path once in the environment and refer to it with a short alias than to waste buffer space in every command.

Comment: @JdeBP: Are you sure that working directories are the same on Windows? On MSDOS each drive `A:`, `B:` had its own wd (but I used it only in the 1980s and I am becoming old, so perhaps I am wrong)

Comment: @chepner: you are right, but today with 16Gbyte RAM in every laptop we don't care.

Comment: Yes, quite sure.  Win32 _is not MS-DOS_ and its working directory semantics are exactly as described here: _one_ working directory per process.  This is famously one of the API differences.  Also note that [POSIX.1 _does not require_ the existence of `..` in _all_ directories](https://askubuntu.com/a/636001/43344).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch The buffer has a fixed size determined by the kernel; it doesn't necessarily have access to all the memory installed on your machine.