# cp behaves weirdly when . (dot) or .. (dot dot) are the source directory

Tags: cp, recursive, hard-link, documentation, dot-files

[This answer](https://superuser.com/a/367303/314879) reveals that one can copy all files - including hidden ones - from directory `src` into directory `dest` like so:

```
mkdir dest
cp -r src/. dest
```

There is no explanation in the answer or its comments as to why this actually works, and nobody seems to find documentation on this either.

I tried out a few things. First, the normal case:

```
$ mkdir src src/src_dir dest && touch src/src_file src/.dotfile dest/dest_file
$ cp -r src dest
$ ls -A dest
dest_file  src
```

Then, with `/.` at the end:

```
$ mkdir src src/src_dir dest && touch src/src_file src/.dotfile dest/dest_file
$ cp -r src/. dest
$ ls -A dest
dest_file  .dotfile  src_dir  src_file
```

So, this behaves simlarly to `*`, but also copies hidden files.

```
$ mkdir src src/src_dir dest && touch src/src_file src/.dotfile dest/dest_file
$ cp -r src/* dest
$ ls -A dest
dest_file  src_dir  src_file
```

`.` and `..` are proper hard-links as [explained here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/332683/67771), just like the directory entry itself.

Where does this behaviour come from, and where is it documented?

Comment: What do you mean nobody can find documentation? The [`cp` reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#cp-invocation) clearly explains how `cp -R` works. `.` and `..` are directories just like any other directories, there is nothing magical or mysterious about them.

Comment: @AlexP I edited the answer to make it clearer. The whole point is that `.` and `..` don't behave like other directories.

Comment: I have tried to explain why it works at [How to copy a folder recursively in an idempotent way using cp](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/228637/100397)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The behaviour is a logical result of the documented algorithm for `cp -R`. See [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cp.html), step 2f:

> The files in the directory *source_file* shall be copied to the directory *dest_file*, taking the four steps (1 to 4) listed here with the files as *source_files*.

`.` and `..` are directories, respectively the current directory, and the parent directory. Neither are special as far as the shell is concerned, so neither are concerned by expansion, and the directory will be copied including hidden files. `*`, on the other hand, will be expanded to a list of files, and this is where hidden files are filtered out.

`src/.` is the current directory inside `src`, which is `src` itself; `src/src_dir/..` is `src_dir`’s parent directory, which is again `src`. So from outside `src`, if `src` is a directory, specifying `src/.` or `src/src_dir/..` as the source file for `cp` are equivalent, and copy the contents of `src`, including hidden files.

The point of specifying `src/.` is that it will fail if `src` is not a directory (or symbolic link to a directory), whereas `src` wouldn’t. It will also copy the contents of `src` only, without copying `src` itself; this matches the documentation too:

> If *target* exists and names an existing directory, the name of the corresponding destination
>   path for each file in the file hierarchy shall be the concatenation of *target*, a single slash
>   character if target did not end in a slash, and the pathname of the file relative to the
>   directory containing *source_file*.

So `cp -R src/. dest` copies the contents of `src` to `dest/.` (the source file is `.` in `src`), whereas `cp -R src dest` copies the contents of `src` to `dest/src` (the source file is `src`).

Another way to think of this is to compare copying `src/src_dir` and `src/.`, rather than comparing `src/.` and `src`. `.` behaves just like `src_dir` in the former case.

Comment: But it doesn't behave the same way. Specifying `src` will copy the directory into `dest`, `src/.` will copy the contents. I'll try to make that clearer in the question.

Comment: There, I think that answers your underlying question.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by _so neither are concerned by expansion (which avoids issues with the shell expanding hidden files or not)_. `cp -r src/.* dest/`  is a problem in shells like `bash` that don't remove `.` and `..` from their globs (fixed in zsh, fish, pdksh (from the Forsyth shell) and derivatives).

Comment: @Stéphane the OP compares copying `src/.` and `src/*` (note, *not* `src/.*`); `src/*` doesn’t include hidden files if globbing ignores them...

Comment: Ah OK. Note that `yash -o dotglob -c 'echo *'` does include `.` and `..`. `*` can include `.` and `..` as well in `ksh` depending on how you configure FIGNORE.

Comment: @Stéphane indeed — I didn’t particulary want to go into globbing subtleties in this answer ;-).

Comment: Hmm, "directory containing _source_file_".  Well, obviously `src` contains `src/.` but it does mean that the containing directory of a directory depends on how you name the directory. Of course the existence of the `.` links in a way means that all directories contain themselves, but that might not be intuitive for all.
Instead of this behaviour, one might also be tempted to assume that "the directory containing directory `foo`" would be determined by `foo/..`, in which case it wouldn't matter if we refer to `foo` or `foo/.`: the resulting containing directory would be the same.

Comment: Which is to say that the distinction between `foo` and `foo/.` seems a bit delicate, but I don't mind, I also find it slightly amusing.

Comment: Not convinced this reading of the spec makes sense. If "the directory containing" `src/.` is `src`, then logically shouldn't "the directory containing" `src/src_dir/..` be `src/src_dir`? In which case, shouldn't *the pathname of the file relative to the directory containing source_file*, for the file `src_dir`, be `../src_dir`? And thus, shouldn't we expect `cp -R src/src_dir/.. target` to create a copy of `src_dir` as a *sibling* of `target`, not a child? Obviously, that's not what `cp` really does, but it seems like it should if we accept your interpretation here. What am I missing?

Comment: @Mark the construction applies to files (and directories) *inside* the source, being copied to the target. Let’s say `src/src_dir` contains a file named `a`. `cp -r src/src_dir/.. target` copies everything inside `src/src_dir/..`, *i.e.* inside `src`; so `src_dir` and `src_dir/a`, which are (after construction based on the given source directory) `src/src_dir/../src_dir` and `src/src_dir/../src_dir/a`. Their paths relative to the source directory are `src_dir` and `src_dir/a`, and the result is `target/src_dir` and `target/src_dir/a`.

Comment: @StephenKitt *"Their paths relative to the source directory are `src_dir` and `src_dir/a`"* - but how can this be consistent with the handling of `.`? If the relative path of `src_dir` when you do `cp -r src` is `src/src_dir`, and the relative path of `src_dir` when you do `cp -r src/.` is `src_dir`, then when you do `cp -r src/src_dir/..` shouldn't the relative path be `../src_dir`? Concluding otherwise seems to mean we should treat `src` as "containing" `src/.`, but *not* treat `src/src_dir` as "containing" `src/src_dir/..`. But... why? What justification for that is there in spec, if any?

Comment: I think this code is relevant to the discussion https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/9f71f478ec6929d323c17f0482db8791de87b4fd/src/cp.c#L705

Answer (score 4):

When you run `cp -R src/foo dest`, you'll get `dest/foo`. So if directory `dest/foo` does not exist, `cp` will create it, and then copy the contents of `src/foo` to `dest/foo`.

When you run `cp -R src/. dest`, `cp` sees that `dest/.` exists, and then it's just the matter of copying the contents of `src/.` to `dest/.`.

When you think of it as copying a directory named `.` from `src` and merging its contents with the existing directory `dest/.`, it will make sense.