# How can I copy a directory and rename it in the same command?

Tags: cp, mv

Currently, I'm running these two commands to create a quick backup of the directory. Is there a way to combine the two commands into one, so that I am copying and renaming the new directory in one command?

```
#cp -R /tf/Custom_App /tf/Custom_App_backups/
#mv /tf/Custom_App_backups/Custom_App /tf/Custom_App_backups/Custom_App_2017-12-21
```

Comment: `cp -R /tf/Custom_App /tf/Custom_App_backups/Custom_App_2017-12-21`

Comment: How about to define alias or function for that two things ;)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You should be able to do just

```
cp -R /tf/Custom_App /tf/Custom_App_backups/Custom_App_2017-12-21
```

*However*, if the target directory already exists, this would append the final part of the source path to the destination path, creating
`/tf/Custom_App_backups/Custom_App_2017-12-21/Custom_App`, and then copy the rest of the tree within that.

To prevent this, use `/tf/Custom_App/.` as the source. Of course, in that case you might want to `rm -r /tf/Custom_App_backups/Custom_App_2017-12-21` first, if you don't want older files lying around there after the copy.

The difference between `/some/dir` and `/some/dir/.` was discussed a while back in [cp behaves weirdly when . (dot) or .. (dot dot) are the source directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/409225/170373)

Comment: An alternative to passing `.` as the source directory is to use the `-T` flag to tell `cp` to overwrite the destination rather than creating a new member inside it.

Comment: @TobySpeight, ... in GNU `cp`.

Comment: The `/tf/Custom_app/.` trick is just what I needed.

Comment: `cp -a` also works.

Comment: @MartinBonner, I agree with you. The answer should have been
```bash
cp -R /tf/Custom_app/. /tf/Custom_App_backups/Custom_App_2017-12-21
```

Comment: @AbelMelquiadesCallejo, wasn't it, then? The second-to-last paragraph says "to prevent this, use `/tf/Custom_App/.` as the source." (there's the magic trailing dot).

Comment: @flow2k, `-a` includes `-R` in the versions of `cp` where it's supported, so yeah, it works. It's just not a standard option, and I don't think it affects the issue at hand.

Comment: @ilkkachu What do you mean when you say `-a` is not a standard option? I do see it listed on https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/cp-invocation.html#cp-invocation.

Comment: @flow2k, GNU utilities in particular have loads of non-standard options, many of them very useful. `cp -a` of course appears also in e.g. [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?cp) and [OpenBSD](https://man.openbsd.org/cp.1) but it's still not a standard feature, that is, not specified by [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/cp.html). (`cp -T` that was mentioned earlier seems a GNUism, it's not in POSIX, and not in the BSDs as far as I can see.)

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, you can do it like so:

```bsh
mkdir /tf/Custom_App_backups/Custom_App_2017-12-21 # prepare the target location
cp -R /tf/Custom_app/. /tf/Custom_App_backups/Custom_App_2017-12-21 # copy only the contents
```

This will allow you to specify your custom location beforehand. Also, notice that it uses the suffix `/.` This allows you to only copy the contents and exclude its containing folder -- in this case it is the `Custom_app` folder.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this page searching for the same advice. On my Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal Fossa) system, I attempted this command and used the same syntax as what @ilkkachu presented. Except I added a trailing slash to my dest folder, eg, dest/ . The result copied the source folder plus its siblings! When I retried without the trailing slash I got the desired result.

So, for future reference, be aware that adding a trailing slash to the dest folder will copy the source siblings as well (.. at least, that was MY experience)

Answer (score -1):

You can easily proceed by creating your target directory:

```
mkdir Custom_App_2017-12-21
cd Custom_App_2017-12-21/
cp -R /tf/Custom_App/* .
```

The last command will copy all your relevant files into a newly-made directory.

Comment: You will have to mention your assumptions: 1) All relevant files have non-hidden filenames. 2) The `*` does not expand to too many names.

Comment: (0) Also, you didn’t state your assumption that the OP has done `cd /tf/Custom_App_backups`.  (1) The question says, “Currently, I'm running *these **two** commands* …  Is there a way *to combine the two commands **into one**,* … *in **one command**?*”  You have replaced the OP’s two commands *with **three**.*  (2) You haven’t added anything here.  In fact, you have subtracted — you have replicated [Abel Melquiades Callejo’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/412259/80216#521368), but made it worse.